# user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

So I already searched in Google and stack, I found a bunch of ppl with the same error but none of the solutions seems to solve my problem.

What I'm using:

- Java 8
- JavaEE7
- TomEE 7.0 M3
- JPA 2.0
- ORM 1.0
- Postgres

I think the problem is with the named query and maybe the ManyToMany relation.

## Here follows the code

#### Entities

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="system_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String login;
    @Column
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_role_relation",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<SystemRole> rolesRelation;

    @Transient
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User(){}

    public List<Role> getRoles(){
        if(this.roles == null){
            List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>(); 
            for(SystemRole relation : rolesRelation){
                roles.add(relation.getCode());
            }
            this.roles = roles;
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(this.roles);
    }

    public String getLogin(){
        return this.login;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

SystemRole.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="system_role")
public class SystemRole{
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role code;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="rolesRelation")
    private List<User> users;

    public SystemRole(){}

    Role getCode(){
        return this.code;
    }

    public static  enum Role {
        MANAGER, EXECUTIVE, HRBP, ADMIN, USER;
    }
}
```

#### XML Configuration

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="Pulse-PU" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/postgresds</jta-data-source>

        <mapping-file>META-INF/user-orm.xml</mapping-file>

        <class>com.appus.pulse.jaas.entity.SystemRole</class>
        <class>com.appus.pulse.jaas.entity.User</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

user-orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <named-query name="User.getByLogin">
        <query>
            SELECT 
               user
            FROM User user 
            JOIN FETCH user.rolesRelation rr
            WHERE user.login = :login
        </query>
    </named-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

context.xml

```
<Context>
      <Resource name="jdbc/postgresds"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        initialSize="5"
        maxActive="55"
        maxIdle="21"
        minIdle="3"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        validationInterval="34"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="233"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pulse"
        username="postgres"
        password=""/>
</Context>
```

Example code that I'm using to return User

#### Resource

TestResource.java

```
@Path("/user-test")
@Produces("plain/text")
@RequestScoped
public class TestResource {

    @EJB(beanName="userdao")
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GET
    public void getTest(){
        userRepository.getByLogin("admin");
        System.out.println("teste");
    }

}
```

#### Interface and DAO

UserRepository.java

```
@Local
public interface UserRepository {
    public User getByLogin(String login);
}
```

UserDAO.java

```
@Stateless(name="userdao")
public class UserDAO implements UserRepository{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Pulse-PU")
    private EntityManager  entityManager;


    public User getByLogin(String login) {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.getByLogin", User.class)
                            .setParameter("login", login)
                            .getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

Finally here is the exception

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SYSTEM_ROLE
Error Code: -5501
Call: SELECT t1.ID, t1.LOGIN, t1.PASSWORD, t0.ID, t0.CODE, t0.NAME FROM system_role t0, user_role_relation t2, system_user t1 WHERE ((t1.LOGIN = ?) AND ((t2.user_id = t1.ID) AND (t0.ID = t2.role_id)))
    bind => [admin]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="User.getByLogin" referenceClass=User sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.LOGIN, t1.PASSWORD, t0.ID, t0.CODE, t0.NAME FROM system_role t0, user_role_relation t2, system_user t1 WHERE ((t1.LOGIN = ?) AND ((t2.user_id = t1.ID) AND (t0.ID = t2.role_id)))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2693)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
    at com.appus.pulse.dao.UserDAO.getByLogin(UserDAO.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:236)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:203)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.getByLogin(Unknown Source)
    at com.appus.pulse.ws.TestResource.getTest(TestResource.java:21)
    at com.appus.pulse.ws.TestResource$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.getTest(com/appus/pulse/ws/TestResource.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:253)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.WebBeansFilter.doFilter(WebBeansFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SYSTEM_ROLE
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1565)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SYSTEM_ROLE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 102 more
```

Sorry about the long post, but I wanted to put every piece of code that matters. So if any info was left out please let me know.
I really don't know what is the problem, I though that the problem would be the absence of public setters, but as far as I know JPA doesn't need to use setter.

Comment: Are you able to query that table manually, with the same account?

Comment: @Todd Yes I'm using the user postgres to connect in the database, if I get the query displayed there and execute in the Pgadmin it returns the right result.

Comment: What is "javax.persistence.jdbc.show_sql"? There is no such standard property

Comment: You say you're using Postgresql but are using HSQLDB in that stack trace! Suggest you fix that first ;-)

Comment: @NeilStockton I think "javax.persistence.jdbc.show_sql" is a valid property, as seen in this [here](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/standard-persistence-properties-in-jpa-2.html)

Comment: @NeilStockton Where I can say to not use HSQLDB? I didn't find anything in the code that suggests that I'm using it. :/

Comment: @KimAragonEscobar No that is NOT a valid property. Look in the JPA SPEC rather than tutorials by who knows. Perhaps if you look in the EclipseLink LOG you will see where the HSQLDB comes from, since there's nothing anyone here can say with what is posted

Comment: Other issues - javax.persistence.jdbc properties are when you define the JDBC connections for outside of a container, but you are using a datasource and JTA within your container.  Check the java:global/jdbc/postgresds datasource you've defined to make sure it points where you think it is pointing.  You also show a "User" entity that maps to a "user" table, but the query uses "system_user", so this isn't the actual configuration/files.

Comment: @Chris Good to know. I'll talk with my team about that, because this initial configurations was made by other members of my development team, so I'm not sure why this properties were included there. Yep the table name is incorrect in the post, I'll fix it. The resource I define in my context.xml I'll include it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I already solved the problem, it was a configuration problem. I noticed that in the persistence.xml it was pointing to the   java:**global**/jdbc/postgresds and I was defining the resource in the context.xml that is in the META-INF in the application directory. The name of the resource is  **jdbc/postgresds**, so I just removed the **global** in the jta-data-source and had to add in the resource JtaManaged="true".

Everything is working just fine now.

Thank you to everyone who commented on this post.